# How do I implement DBString.length in my model?

Tags: odbc, dapper, informix

Say I have the following Informix table structure:

```
tablename = clients
field = firstname CHAR(30)
```

And a Model much like this:

```
public class Clients
{
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string firstname { get; set; }
}
```

I know I can declare firstname as a DbString type and set IsAnsi and Length:

```
con.Execute(@" insert Clients(firstname) values(?firstname?)", 
    new { firstname = new DbString { Value = "John", IsAnsi = true, Length = 30 }});
```

But when I pass in the model above to dapper, it results in "Illegal attempt to convert Text Byte blob type" because dapper is assuming the string firstname is a text type rather than a fixed string:

```
con.Execute(@" insert Clients(firstname) values(?firstname?)", Clients);
```

I couldn't find any examples showing how to either:

1. define the string length as a custom attribute in a model and inform dapper to use the customer attribute and define the string as a DbString with a length
2. tell dapper to use the StringLength data annotation attribute in a model (It seems to me that this would be ideal since it is likely that validation is already in use and dapper could make a better assumption of the string)

I'm unsure if a shim is the proper usage for this case.

Comment: @A_J `name` is `CHAR` because that's how it was defined back in 1980.  It won't get changed unless the server and backups catch on fire!  I'm not sure what you mean by passing an instance of `Clients`... isn't that what I did in my last statement?  `con.Execute(@" insert Clients(firstname) values(?firstname?)", Clients);`

Comment: Note that a CHAR(30) column can have up to 30 characters in it; if you need to account for a null terminator, you have to add one somewhere along the line (but I've no idea where).  Further, in some scenarios (but not necessarily those involving ODBC), you might find that the string is always blank-padded to 30 characters (plus null).  There are endless ways that could be irrelevant information.

Comment: @jonathanleffler that is worth pointing out, thank you.  it gives me another avenue to try/test.  i'll try monday, appeding a null terminator, but im not optimistic it'll be that simple.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I tried appending a null character but that didn't resolve it.